# Python - long halt while calculating palindrome number

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, palindrome, halting-problem

I'm trying to find largest palindromic number made from the product of two 3-digit numbers with my code. it works fine for 2-digit and 3-digit, but when I try it with 4-digit numbers, it doesn't work anymore. There is no output or "Process finished with exit code 0" at the end. It just halted like it was in an infinite loop.

```
palin = 0
for x in range(1, 10000):
    for y in range(1, 10000):
        mult = x * y

        if str(mult) == str(mult)[::-1]:
            if mult > palin:
                palin = mult

print(palin)
```

where did I go wrong? I just started Python about a month ago, so my code is still not effective

Comment: It's kinda an infinite loop, you know, it's very long...

Comment: Your algorithm does not halt. It's slow (and it's wrong). So you have to *wait for some minutes* before getting any output.

Comment: It's the 4th problem in PrjectEuleur's website called `Largest palindrome product`. Your algorithm isn't correct and it's not an infinite loop. But it may take a long time to finish the calculations. Better way is optimizing your code. Maybe with some maths...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is not correct. The second `if` should be at the same level as `mult = x*y`.

I modified your code a little bit. With the code below you see that the algorithm does not halt. It's just super slow. You'll have to wait for minutes.

```
pa = 0
for x in range(1, 10000):
    if x % 100 == 0:
        print(x)
    for y in range(x, 10000):
        m = x*y
        if str(m) == str(m)[::-1]:
            if m > pa:
                pa = m
print(pa)
```

I changed the second `range(1, 10000)` to `range(x, 10000)` to eliminate duplicates like 1*2 and 2*1 into a single 1*2.

If you want a speedup, consider switching to C or C++.

Also you can reverse the iteration order for an extreme speedup

```
for x in range(10000, 0, -1):
    for y in range(10000, 0, -1):
        m = x*y
        if str(m) == str(m)[::-1]:
            print(m)
            exit(0)
```

Comment: sorry my bad...it was actually the same level as mult = x * y. I put it wrong, and I've edited it

Comment: You cut the time in half with this code, with my earlier code it took around 115 seconds, but with your code, it only took 61 seconds, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda an infinite loop, you know, it's very long...

But actually somehow (maybe my computer is fast :-)) the code ran around 15 seconds only...

So it's good.

No halt in it, it's just slow.

Comment: This code does not cover all the circumstances the OP wants to consider. You code only test like  1*1, 2*2, 3*3 .... The OP wants to test   1*1, 1*2, 1*3 ... 2*1, 2*2, 2*3.... 10000*1, 10000*2 ... 10000*10000. Using zip, you only tested 0.01% of all the situations.

Comment: @Hoblovski Done!